# Retrieve all file names in a folder using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve a list of all files names in a folder, regardless of their extension eg.txt. The files will mostly be .wav.

So far I have:

```
    public string GetSoundFile(string pSoundFolder)
    {
        string[] pFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pSoundFolder, "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        string pFileList = "";
        for (int ii = 0; ii < pFiles.Length; ii++)
        {
            pFileList += "|" + pFiles[ii];                      
        }

        return (pFileList);
    }
```

The function is being called by using an AJAX call using JavaScript.

I call the AJAX as follows:

```
oGetSoundFilesJAXHandler.call("C:\\Projects");
```

The problem is, it is returning blank.

I have tried counting the number of files in the folder as follows:

```
int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(pSoundFolder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
```

But it still returns blank.

I have tried adjusting the path to:

```
oGetSoundFilesJAXHandler.call("C:\\Projects\\");
```

But no luck, and I have tried setting the file path using '@':

```
string[] pFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@pSoundFolder, "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

But still no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you debug the code while executing it? What is the actual argument used for `pSoundFolder`? It might also be an access permissions issue.

Comment: Ignore the input parameter for now and just put in a hardcoded path in your GetSoundFile() method, then see if it yields a result. Are you sure that path is correct? (Also, calling a method over AJAX containing a file path is asking for trouble, I wouldn't do that!)

Comment: I have solved, it. The code was all working fine, I just had not told the AJAX to write the response back to the JavaScript. I agree about sending file paths using AJAX. I am building in steps, so will address this further along in the development process.

Comment: Instead of accepting folder paths from clients, you could, instead, accept some alias (like a library name) and have that mapped to a folder in your server-side code using some dictionary whatever data structure you want, but most importantly, that you control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute that code in a simple console application, if it works there then you are 100% sure that the code is actually fine and that it is an access issue.
Put exception handling around the code to be sure it does not throw any exceptions .

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but try using WebMethod, your method is working correctly though:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetSoundFile(string pSoundFolder)
        {
            string[] pFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pSoundFolder, "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            string pFileList = "";
            for (int ii = 0; ii < pFiles.Length; ii++)
            {
                pFileList += "|" + pFiles[ii];                      
            }

            return (pFileList);
        }
```